# When I try and add 2 roles or more with one command, it removes them

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to add the role "Blue" and "Verified" with this command. I can do them both separately, but whenever I try to add it with one command, it always adds "Blue" then removes it, but adds "verified".

```
if(msg.content === "Yes" ){
    const arr = ['878722965972348938', '878722966660214844', '878722965070544926']
    if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => arr.includes(r.id))) return message.channel.send('⚠️You already have it assigned')
        try{
        message.member.roles.add(Blue)
        .then()
        message.member.roles.add(Verified)     
        message.channel.send(`${msg.content} Assigned✅`);
        message.channel.send(`Go to <#879068760374378566> to complete verification!`);
    } catch(error) {
        message.channel.send("⚠️Error has occurred, please contact server adminstrator.");
        console.log(error)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your question must be self-contained: your code must be included as text in the body of the question as a [mre]. External links tend to break or change over time and diminish value for future visitors to this question. See also: [ask]

Comment: i think `Lincoln` in not in the scope (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: Lincoln works fine and adds the role, only GOP, DEM, and IND are having issues (line 169 and down)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the role but not `await`ing it. Trying to add the other role after conflicts with adding the first role and just adds the `Verified` role on its own. [`GuildMemberRoleManager.add`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) accepts an array. You can change your current code from

```js
message.member.roles.add(Blue).then()
message.member.roles.add(Verified)
```

To this

```js
message.member.roles.add([Blue, Verified])
```